# Getting sortedArray of values from a HashMultiMap

Tags: java, sorting, collections, multimap

i have two hashmultimaps . how do i compare the values of the multimap for a given key.

i thought i would generate a TreeSet from HashMultiMap
something like
ts1=new TreeSet(hmap.get(key))
ts2=new TreeSet(hmap.get(key))

and then iterate over one tree set and then check if that element is there in the other tree set.

Is there a java class that generates a sorted array given a collection?

Comment: What language are you using? Java, C++, C#?

Comment: java...sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: What do you want to check exactly? That every element in the first set is in the second one? Something else? Why would you need to transform the set into a TreeSet or a sorted array to do that?

Comment: yes.those in the first set and not in the second set and those in the second set and not in the first set

Comment: Why do you want a sorted array instead of a sorted collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<Foo> a = multimap1.get(key);
Set<Foo> b = multimap2.get(key);

Set<Foo> inAButNotInB = Sets.difference(a, b);
Set<Foo> inBButNotInA = Sets.difference(b, a);
```